# Python is there anyway to obtain user uid from firebase?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, pyrebase

is there anyway that i can get the uid of the users in my firebase database? I want to do this so i would be able to store data based on their accounts and also currently looking for a way to create a sign out function.I have tried:

auth.signOut() but it is not supported.

print(user[“idToken”]) i was able to get the token id after logging in using the accounts but for some reason it is not unique between each users hence i dont think i wil be able to store the data. Still testing at the moment.

Comment: Have you tried `print(user[“localId”])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(user[“localId”])` should print the user ID.

Answer (score 1):

You will get idtoken for a user by sign in. Then use this token to get user details including uid.

```
import pyrebase
from firebase_admin import credentials, auth
pb = pyrebase.initialize_app(json.load(open('fbconfig.json')))

# signin 
result = pb.auth().sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password) 

# get user details using token
user = auth.verify_id_token(result['idToken'])
print(user['uid'])
```

Comment: gonna try this. Hopefully it works as i am also trying to check if the user is really logged in after entering their credentials and moving onto the next page. For this to work do i need to install the firebase_admin sdk?